# Find out the file extension in JFileChooser

Tags: java, swing, export, jfilechooser

I already have a method which export data as a csv. No I need to implement an export as a xml and as a java object itself.
So I need to know, as what the user will save it. I want to find out what extention he insert in the already made JFileChooser.

Here's the code I already have:

```
JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
int opt = chooser.showSaveDialog(frame);
if (opt != JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
    return;
try {
    File file = chooser.getSelectedFile();
    export(file);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, file,
            getText("message.filesaved"),
            JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
} catch (Exception e) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, e.getMessage(),
            getText("message.error"), JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
}
```

So how can I extend this method to allow the user, to choose if he will export it as a csv (already done), xml or java object?

*What I already tried:*
I tried to use the `FileNameExtensionFilter` to add a CSV option, a XML option or a Java Object option. But with this method, I can't find out which one the user took.

Comment: do you want to add .csv/xml automatically without any users action ??? (is simple and possible)

Comment: @mKorbel: if this is possible... Then I could see if it will work with that way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already added FileFilters, you can simply use the getFileFilter() method.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html#getFileFilter%28%29

It will return the selected FileFilter and all you have to do is to append the extention to the file name.